# mysql query fails if name has more then 1 words

Tags: php, mysql

I began to create a website for my small real estate business.
I played a bit with functions http://www.php.net mysql and I managed to make a page accessed via AJAX and returning html content for the search engine.

I have a database already populated with apartments and houses

The problem is that if the apartment name is "apartment" I return html content if "apartment with 3 rooms" it no longer write anything.

I do not understand where I was wrong:

```
<?php
    $search = $_GET['selected'];

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('houses', $link);

    function searchHouse($search, $link){
        $query = "select * from houses where name=$search limit 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $query2 = "select * from houses_info where house_id=$row[id]";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
        return $row;
    }

    $result = searchHouse($search, $link);

    echo $result['house_sq'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $result['house_rooms'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $result['house_bathrooms'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $result['house_address'];

    ?>
```

Comment: `echo $query;` and answer - do you think the query is correct?

Comment: That's because you're using input directly in a query with no escaping, validating or formatting.  If you get it to echo out the query with different values it should become obvious why it's breaking.  This code is wide open to SQL injection, you're using deprecated mysql_* functions (use PDO or mysqli instead) and you're not doing error checking.

Comment: 1. Prone to SQL injections.
2. Do **NOT** use `mysql_*` functions.
3. What type of table and indexes you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- you should know if you "played" with [php.net](http://www.php.net) that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and are no longer maintained. It's a red box on top of the page informing you that.
- you have a big `MySQL` injection hole there, you are not escaping `$string` at all
- your problem is that you are not adding quotes to `$string` like: `'$string'`
- you should stat using `PDO` to get rid of the bad code and SQL Injections holes.
- you can wrap those 2 selects into a single select:

  ```
  <?php
      function searchHouse($search, $link){
          $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
          $query = "select * from houses_info where house_id IN (select * from houses where name='".$search."' limit 1)";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
          return $row;
      }
  ?>
  ```
- since you are already building that website you can start moving to `PDO`, read this [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), your code will be more like this:

  ```
  <?php
      $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=houses;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
      $search = $_GET['selected'];

      function searchHouse($search){
          global $db;

          $query = $db->prepare("select * from houses_info where house_id IN (select * from houses where name=:search limit 1)");
          $query->execute(array(':search' => $search));
          $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          return $row;
      }

      $result = searchHouse($search);
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Why use `IN` over `=` with `id` instead of `*`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$query = "select * from houses where name='".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."' limit 1";
```

and remember to always sanitize user input before passing it to sql to avoid sql injections.

Answer (score -2):

Strings need to be quoted in queries. Also, this is vulnerable to MySQL injection, make sure to escape $search with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Or even better yet use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead of the old mysql_ functions.

```
$query = "select * from houses where name=$search limit 1";
```

Should be:

```
$query = "select * from houses where name='$search' limit 1";
```

Although you REALLY need to escape $search because it came from a user, even if they aren't malicious, any search queries with a single quote in it will break;

```
$search = $_GET['selected'];
```

Should be:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['selected']);
```

(Anybody have the copy paste handy with the links to tutorials for MySQLi/PDO and such?)

Comment: And how about some mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: that's still wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Wanted to get the answer posted first, I added that in.

Comment: "Wanted to get the answer posted first" o_O

Comment: I wanted to make the specific problem cleared first before mentioning the security of the code. Is it really that wrong?

Comment: @Alex Lunix: yep, it is terribly wrong - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240092/mysql-query-fails-if-name-has-more-then-1-words#comment16405154_12240116 Op doesn't bother reading comments and even trying to think about the code, all he needs is just to copy-paste the code.

Comment: sorry, i am learning new stuff every day, and i dont fully understand the codes but i will try to learn.

Comment: @user1642439 It's fine, make sure to use PDO or MySQLi (You can find comparisons between them online) instead of mysql_* functions as they are out of date and will not be maintained.

Answer (score -2):

Your first query should be:

$query = "select * from houses where name like $search% limit 1";